# JTable set column width with a dynamic size and JTextArea as cell renderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to set my JTable column with a dynamic size depending on the text. I want to know for each `X` number I set to `getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(X);` how many characters can fit in? ( Font is **Arial** and Font Size is **12** )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know for each X number I set to getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(X); how many characters can fit in?

You can't get a general answer because the string "iiiii" will take less than "wwwww", since each character can take a different number of pixels.

Instead you actually need to determine the size of each cell individually and then use the maximum. You would do this after the data has been loaded into the table.

The basic code would be:

```
JTable table = new JTable( ... );
table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );

for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++)
{
    TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
    int preferredWidth = tableColumn.getMinWidth();
    int maxWidth = tableColumn.getMaxWidth();

    for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++)
    {
        TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
        Component c = table.prepareRenderer(cellRenderer, row, column);
        int width = c.getPreferredSize().width + table.getIntercellSpacing().width;
        preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, width);

        //  We've exceeded the maximum width, no need to check other rows

        if (preferredWidth >= maxWidth)
        {
            preferredWidth = maxWidth;
            break;
        }
    }

    tableColumn.setPreferredWidth( preferredWidth );
}
```

The above code will provide a static width for each column.

Another option is to use the [Table Column Adjuster](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/). The `Table Column Adjuster` incorporates the above logic with additional features and can be used to determine column widths:

1. based on the data in the header, each cell or both
2. statically (after data is loaded into the `TableModel`) or dynamically (as data is edited or added to the `TableModel`).

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need:

```
JTable table = new JTable(){
    @Override
       public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
           Component component = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
           int rendererWidth = component.getPreferredSize().width;
           TableColumn tableColumn = getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
           tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(rendererWidth + getIntercellSpacing().width, tableColumn.getPreferredWidth()));
           return component;
        }
    };
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

The table will adjust each column width automatically to fit the content. There's no need to control when to trigger the resizing.

Comment: You should not change the size of a component during the rendering process.

Comment: You should try and see for yourself. It works perfectly and I never had a single issue with it. This is the best solution for this requirement by far.

Comment: The point of rendering code is to render components, not set the preferred width of a TableColumn. The code might work on static data that never changes, in which case it would be overhead to continually execute the code when it could be done once after the data it loaded. Yes it does increase the width if the data changes, but it does not decrease the width so the column width can only ever grow. Based on the requirement this may be acceptable.

Comment: I have `JTextArea` as renderer.  `getIntercellSpacing().width` always return 1